# Passing data to another page to be used in a GD image generation function

Tags: php, gd

I have a block of code that will turn a string into an image of the text. For it to work correctly in my implementation it needs to be in a separate file.

So I have this: (generateimage.php)

```
<?php
$text = "this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test";

$arrText = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 69, "\n")); //change number 75 here to check the wordwrap

$im = @imagecreate(650, 500); //creates an image (width,height)
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //sets image background color
$y = 5; //vertical position of text

foreach ($arrText as $key => $arr)
{
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); //sets text color
//imagestring($im, 5, 15, $y, trim($arr), $white); //create the text string for image,added trim() to remove unwanted chars
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 15, 16 + $y, $white, 'font.ttf', trim($arr));
$y = $y + 16 + 4; // size of font + newline space
}

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I then call it in my main page with this:

```
<img src="generateimage.php">
```

What I want to do is pass a variable to fill $text in generateimage.php. How would I go about doing this? There will be an article to pass across so (1000+ words), I don't think passing it via GET (URL) would be good.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you familiar with GET requests? By the way, such a service can be easily abused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way, imho, is to put your string into either database or file or, maybe, session var by some script, set some short ID for selected text instance  and then use GET to pass this ID to generateimage.php